# convert all xlsx files in directory to text

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I am trying to create a button in a .`xlsm` that will convert each of the ~100 `.xlsx` files in the `myFolder` directory to `.txt`. The below `VBA` code returns an `Expected End Sub`error. The data is always in `Sheet 1" even though there may be other sheets present.

The `Dos` command executes and converts the files but they are unreadable (something to do with excels formatting?). I am not sure what to do?  Thank you :)

Dos

```
cd C:\Users\Desktop\folder
Copy *.xlsx *.txt
```

**VBA**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()


Dim oFSO, myFolder
Dim xlText

myFolder = "C:\Users\Desktop\folder"


Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
xlText = -4158 'Excel txt format enum
Call ConvertAllExcelFiles(myFolder)
Set oFSO = Nothing

Call MsgBox("Done!")


Sub ConvertAllExcelFiles(ByVal oFolder)
Dim targetF, oFileList, oFile
Dim oExcel, oWB, oWSH

Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
oExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
Set targetF = oFSO.GetFolder(oFolder)
Set oFileList = targetF.Files
For Each oFile In oFileList
If (Right(oFile.Name, 4) = "xlsx") Then
    Set oWB = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(oFile.Path)
    For Each oWSH In oWB.Sheets
        Call oWSH.SaveAs(oFile.Path & ".txt", FileFormat:=xlTextWindows)
    Next
    Set oWSH = Nothing
    Call oWB.Close
    Set oWB = Nothing
End If
Next
Call oExcel.Quit
Set oExcel = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first lines of your code belong in `Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()`
(it has to be closed by `End Sub`)

`Option Explicit` and proper code indentation can help in this situation

Try this version:

---

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim myFolder As String

    myFolder = "C:\Users\Desktop\folder"
    ConvertAllExcelFiles myFolder
    MsgBox "Done!"
End Sub

Public Sub ConvertAllExcelFiles(ByVal folderPath As String)
    Dim xlApp As Object, wb As Workbook, ws As Variant, fso As Object
    Dim fileList As Object, itm As Object, fileName As String

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set fileList = fso.GetFolder(folderPath).Files
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False

    For Each itm In fileList
        If Right(itm.Name, 4) = "xlsx" Then
            Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(itm.Path)
            fileName = fso.GetParentFolderName(itm.Path) & "\" & fso.GetBaseName(itm.Path)
            If True Then    'if converting all sheets use For loop (Change True to False)
                wb.Sheets(1).SaveAs fileName & ".txt", FileFormat:=xlTextWindows
            Else
                For Each ws In wb.Sheets
                  ws.SaveAs fileName & " - " & ws.Name & ".txt", FileFormat:=xlTextWindows
                Next
                Set ws = Nothing
            End If
            wb.Close:   Set wb = Nothing
        End If
    Next
    xlApp.Quit
End Sub
```

---

Comment: I'm glad it helped. I made small changes and improved text file names: the initial version saved the file as `Book1.xlsx.txt` (now it saves it as `Book1.txt`)